# Using JunitCore for tests in different projects

Tags: java, eclipse, junit

Background:

I am currently working on a project in eclipse that programatically executes JUnit tests that are pushed to a server.

So far everything works but I would like to know the results of the tests (specifically any failures) so I can push them out to an email. Right now the tests just output to the console but that doesn't seem to give me much output to actually use.

Right now I use the Runtime class to call the tests but that doesn't seem to have the functionality I need for getting results.
I have looked into the JUnitCore class but can't call any tests outside of the current java project.

---

So my main question would be how can I use JUnitCore to run junit tests in a specific JAR file? Or is there an easier way to approach this problem using a different class?

This is the only thing I've been able to get to work:

```java
RunTests()
    {
        junitCore = new JUnitCore();

        junitCore.run(AllTests.class);
    }
```

But I would like to do something along the lines of this:

```
RunTests()
    {
        junitCore = new JUnitCore();

        junitCore.run("C:\\$batch\\test\\hil research\\201507071307\\CommsTestRunner\\plugins\\TestSuite\\US35644.class");
    }
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to this problem I am having. I'm an EE and was just introduced to java last month so this has been quite the challenge for me.

Answer (score 0):

JUnitCore expects to read loaded classes, not class files in a JAR. Your real question is likely how to load the JAR (or directory of `.class` files) so it can be run.

Poke around with [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#URLClassLoader(java.net.URL[])); once you've amended the classpath appropriately, you can get a Class out of `findClass` and pass it into the JUnitCore methods you've found.

Answer (score 0):

Since the tests might have classes that are also used by your server (but not necessarily at the same version) I would suggest not having your server directly run the tests. Instead, you can have your server start a new JVM that runs the tests. This is how IDEs like Eclipse run tests. You simply need to write a main class that has JUnit run the tests, and serializes the results on disk.

Your main class would look something like this:

```
public class MyRunner {
  public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    String path = System.getProperty("resultPath");
    if (path == null) {
      throw new NullPointerException("must specify resultPath property");
    }

    // Possibly install a security manager to prevent calls to System.exit()

    Result result = new JUnitCore().runMain(new RealSystem(), args);

    try (ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(path)) {
      out.writeObject(result);
    }      

    System.exit(result.wasSuccessful() ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Then your server simply needs to construct a `java` command line with the jars that include the tests, the JUnit jar file, and a jar that contains `MyRunner`.